# Running a projetct with IntelliJ gives "Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'." but the same project runs ok when started by command line

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster, npm-install, gradlew

I have a jhipster project that runs just fine when started by the command line "./gradlew" (Ubuntu 20.04.3) but when I start the debbug from the IntelliJ (community) it returns the follow message:

***What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':npmInstall'.

A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''***

And I need to run it on IntelliJ to use breakpoints and debug.

What I have tried:

- I have checked the java version on the IntelliJ compiller
- I have the PATH's set correct (I can run other projects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to redefine things, deleting the "node-modules" folder, 'invalidating and restart' on intelliJ and even checking-out the entire project from git, what did the trick was to change the block on build.gradle, from:

```
if (project.hasProperty("nodeInstall")) {
    node {
        version = "14.16.0"
        npmVersion = "7.8.0"
        download = true
    }
}
```

to

```
node {
    version = "14.16.0"
    npmVersion = "7.8.0"
    download = true
}
```

That fixed the problem and now I can debbug using intelliJ